# Which one is the correct assertion in the end? (projectivity of moduli of polarized varieties)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, moduli-spaces

I randomly came across a 2007 [article by Kollár](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0501294v2.pdf) in which the author makes a mathematical statement and explicitly states that it is in contradiction with a result contained in a 2004 [article by Schumacher--Tsuji](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v159-n2-p03.pdf).

So, just out of curiosity: how has the matter settled since 2007? Are there non-quasi-projective moduli spaces of polarized varieties, or not?

Comment: What does MathSciNet say?

Comment: Dude, the title of that article by Kollár should give you a hint. This question was settled with that article. What else do you expect? This is not a philosophical debate where someone might come up with something new that will invalidate what Kollár did.

Comment: Tsuji has used  of Ricci iteration method in this paper you mentioned, I personally couldn't accept his method. I asked a lot of well known mathematicians, nobody accepted his method up to now